# How to fix the look of rendered string in Java

Tags: java, string, swing, fonts, paintcomponent

I am drawing a string in a JPanel with a pixel font. Some parts of the letters are drawn with extra pixels so it looks wider. How can I remove those extra pixels? Here's what it looks like.

[image: three rendered strings with different looks]

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    
    Graphics2D gtd = (Graphics2D) g;
    
    gtd.setFont(new Font("EXEPixelPerfect", Font.PLAIN, 50));
    gtd.drawString("continue", 100, 100);

    gtd.setFont(new Font("EXEPixelPerfect", Font.PLAIN, 51));
    gtd.drawString("continue", 100, 150);

    gtd.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    gtd.setFont(new Font("EXEPixelPerfect", Font.PLAIN, 50));
    gtd.drawString("continue", 100, 200);
    
}
```

The first text is what I have originally. As you can see in the picture, some parts are wider.

In the second text, I increased the font size by one. I want it to look like that, but it's still not fixed. A part of 'e' looks wider.

The third text has the same font format with the first text but it has anti-alias. It fixed the wide lines but the problem is, it looks blurry.

Comment: What are you trying to do, make the font look monospace? Could you please draw an example of what you want the font to look like? If you're not using a monospace font, you could draw character by character and offset the x-coordinate by a fixed value. Alternatively, here are some monospaced "pixel" fonts: https://www.fontspace.com/category/monospaced,pixel

Comment: I've already stated that I want the 'original text' to look like the 'second text', or the 'third text' but not blurry. The look of the 'second text' is almost what I want but it's not perfect.  If I understand correctly, drawing the string by characters seems inefficient.

Comment: 1) make sure you invoke super.paintComponent(...) first to clear the background. 2) You don't want to use antialiasing. antialiasing will add extra pixels to try to blend the foreground with background. 3) what you see is what the font does. If it looks too wide for you, well that is the way the font designers designed the font. Maybe the font works better when an odd size font is used? My suggestion would be to use the odd sized font and not try to force the even sized font to look differently.

Comment: Thanks. I've learned something new about using monospaced fonts. I did invoked super.paintComponent(Graphics g) in my code. I guess the best I can do is try to make my own monospaced font.